# I2C C Programming Nothing Works

Tags: raspberry-pi

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <linux/i2c.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define I2C_SLAVE  0x0703

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uint8_t data, i2c_device_address = 0x21,
    i2c_register_address = 0x01;

    int file, rc;

   //Open I2C
    file = open("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
    if (file < 0)
      err(errno, "Tried to open /dev/i2c-1"); 


    // I want to work with I2C Register at I2C Address 0x12
    rc = ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, i2c_register_address);
    if (rc < 0)
        err(errno, "Tried to set device address '0x%02x'",
             i2c_device_address);


     // Read Content of I2C Register at I2C Address 0x12
     rc = read(file, &data, 1);
     if (rc < 0)
         err(errno, "Tried to read device at address '0x%02x'",
             i2c_device_address);

     // Print the Result
     // Expected (Default) Value = 0x80
     // What i got = 0x00
     printf("/dev/i2c-1: device 0x%02x at address 0x%02x: 0x%02x\n",
             i2c_device_address, i2c_register_address, data);


     // Terminal Output:
     // /dev/i2c-1: device 0x21 at address 0x01: 0x00

     return 0;

}
```

I have the ov7670 camera and i am trying to read some registers for warm up.

But i always get the same result: 0x00.
The datasheet of the camera tells me that 0x80 is the default value for this register.

When my camera isn't even connected to my Raspberry PI it still prints the same output when i run my program. There are not even errors.

I used the command i2cdetect -r 1 and i got correct output.

So the device must be ok and properly connected.

I want to know how can i read and write to i2c registers with the basic Linux read, write & ioctl functions?

***UPDATE***
Now I check the return value of the read function and it says Remote I/O error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ioctl` takes the device address as the third parameter, not the register:

```
rc = ioctl(file, I2C_SLAVE, i2c_device_address);
```

Then, you need a write-read combination, first writing the register you want to read then do the `read`.

And you have to check the return value of the `read`. It needs to be `1` or the `read` failed.

Comment: Ok, but how do i specify the I2C device register for my write-read combination.

Comment: The write operation contains the register address. Refer to the manual of the IC whether it's a 1- oder 2-byte address.